# function template explicit specializatioin

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ template and i have a question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
size_t GetStringSize(const T& s) { return s.size(); }

template<>
size_t GetStringSize(const char* s) { return s.strlen(); }


template<typename T,typename... types>
size_t GetStringSize(const T& arg, types... args) {
    return GetStringSize(arg) + GetStringSize(args...);
}

int main() {
    
    int n = GetStringSize("faf");
    cout << n << endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

`template<> size_t GetStringSize(const char* s) { return s.strlen(); }` 
in here, i got error

Error E0493 : no instance of overloaded function "GetStringSize" matches the specified type.

i think there is nothing wrong with using explicit specialization.

what's wrong with this?

help me please..

Comment: A `const char*` pointer doesn't have a `strlen()` function. You wanted `strlen(s);`. VTC as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem #1**:  You are missing the include that declares `strlen`.  Your compiler may allow this omission, but the next version may not!

```
#include <cstring>
```

**Problem #2**:  You are misusing `strlen` syntax.

```
return strlen(s);
```

**Problem #3**: `const char*` cannot be a specialization of `const T&` because it is not a reference and is not const (it's a **non-const pointer** to something const).

```
 template<>
 size_t GetStringSize(const char*const & s) { return strlen(s); }
```

**Problem #4**: `"faf"` has the type `const char[4]`, so you are going to get the wrong match anyway.  You probably want a *new template* rather than a specialization.

```
template <size_t N>
size_t GetStringSize(const char(&s)[N]) { return strlen(s); }

// For raw pointers
size_t GetStringSize(const char* s) { return strlen(s); }
```

Comment: thanks you so much.  will go over it one by one.